# Too many class calls, or is this proper?

Tags: html, css

Ok so basically I was working on a color scale and I'm not new to html and css programming, but I have this problem, that problem being, a cluster of classes being called in separate paragraph tags. To me it doesn't look very good just because it's all jumbled up; class, after class, is there another approach to this. I do how ever have an external css style sheet so I didn't write it within my html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Color</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Color.css">
 </head>
   <body>
     <h1>pH Scale</h1>
     <p class="fourteen">14.0 VERY ALKALINE</p>
     <p class="thirteen">13.0</p>
     <p class="twelve">12.0</p>
     <p class="eleven">11.0</p>
     <p class="ten">10.0</p>
     <p class="nine">9.0</p>
     <p class="eight">8.0</p>
     <p class="seven">7.0 NEUTRAL</p>
     <p class="six">6.0</p>
     <p class="five">5.0</p>
     <p class="four">4.0</p>
     <p class="three">3.0</p>
     <p class="two">2.0</p>
     <p class="one">1.0</p>
     <p class="zero">0.0 VERY ACID</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question ? what do want o achieve ?

Comment: That looks orderly to me, not jumbled up at all - just very verbose. If anything I would say that it's not appropriate to use paragraphs to mark up a pH scale.

Comment: If you're going the class route I'd say that there aren't enough classes, and the existing class names are not specific enough. `ph` along with `ph-0`-`ph-14` would seem more reasonable to me for classes. That said, I'd recommend skipping the classes altogether and use `[data-ph="#"]` attributes instead.

Comment: Id is better and will be fast here than using class. @zzzzBov suggestion is very good if you apply.

Comment: @zzzzBov: can you give a more detailed example of you approach?

Comment: I guess more or less if it is too verbose, is there a more appropriate approach, meaning is it just short hand i need to focus on or is there a completely different way to implement what I wrote?

Comment: @user3141270 yes, there is. Don't add classes at all. What you want to achieve once again? Add a different color through CSS to each `p`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan basically the class calls a, background-color: Rgb(x,x,x), for each class from my .css file. So, basically my implementation is wrong and I should be using id's? basically I don't want to see a cluster of class calls like what you see here. I just want to make maybe one or two and still have the same out come. Is that obtainable, or wishful thinking?

Comment: @samitha  I don't want to see a cluster of class calls like what you see here. I just want to make maybe one or two and still have the same out come. Is that obtainable, or wishful thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS it will be painful and verbose like adding classes in HTML.
**So I would use JS or jQuery** like in the following example. 
Thanks to **`hsla` colors** you can do it in a couple of lines:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aGIgAyA/1/edit)**

<sub>**Note: wrap all your `p` into a `<div id="scale">`**</sub>

```
var $p = $('#scale p'),
    len = 360/$p.length;

$p.css({background: function(i){
  return "hsla("+(i*len)+",50%,70%, 0.9)";
}});
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I was trying the same thing, you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine if your going to use the classes elsewhere within your project, if your not then you should use id's. Or you could use CSS to change the color and so forth like this.

HTML

```
<div id="ph_wrap">
   <p>One</p>
   <p>Two</p>
   <p>Three</p>
   <p>Four</p>
   <p>Five</p>
   <p>Six</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ph_wrap p:nth-child(1){
   color:red;
}

#ph_wrap p:nth-child(2){
   color:green;
}

...
```

You could also use jquery if you wanted to. But as I stated above your code is fine if your using the classes elsewhere and not just within this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nth-of-child`:

```
<div class="scale">
    <h1>pH Scale</h1>
    <p>14.0 VERY ALKALINE</p>
    <p>13.0</p>
    <p>12.0</p>
    <p>11.0</p>
    <p>10.0</p>
    <p>9.0</p>
    <p>8.0</p>
    <p>7.0 NEUTRAL</p>
    <p>6.0</p>
    <p>5.0</p>
    <p>4.0</p>
    <p>3.0</p>
    <p>2.0</p>
    <p>1.0</p>
    <p>0.0 VERY ACID</p>
</div>
```

css

```
div.scale p:nth-of-type(1) { /* 14 */ };
div.scale p:nth-of-type(2) { /* 13 */ };
/* ... */
```